# Remove values if they are inside an array

Tags: php, algorithm, for-loop

I have a function which is quite intensive in my algorithm.

I want to try to make it as efficient as possible. I don't care too much for readability or anything like that. Just speed.

The basis of the function is to take a set of cards:

```
$card1, $card2, $card3, $card4, $card5, $card6, $card7
```

Where each card is a numeric value.

I then have an array of values that need to be removed from the above set.

$remove_values = array(1,4,3,8,12);

So basically, what I need to do is, if $card1 to $card7 appear in the Remove Values, set that card to 0.

My current function:

```
foreach($remove_values as $value) {
    if($value === $card1) {
        $card1 = 0;
    }
    if($value === $card2) {
        $card2 = 0;
    }
    if($value === $card3) {
        $card3 = 0;
    }
    if($value === $card4) {
        $card4 = 0;
    }
    if($value === $card5) {
        $card5 = 0;
    }
    if($value === $card6) {
        $card6 = 0;
    }
    if($value === $card7) {
        $card7 = 0;
    }
}
```

This works. But I was wondering if there was a more faster way of doing it? Calling php functions is intensive, so I'm trying to reduce the amount of those calls.

I'm literally trying to shave off miliseconds due to my algorithm having to loop through millions of results.

Comment: Is $cards also inside an array ?

Comment: Take a look at [array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter) and the other array functions built into php.

Comment: @PedroLobito it isn't- but it can be. Adding to more arrays causes more overhead.

Comment: Is there any range of value that card can has? For example: between 1 to 100. Something like this.

Comment: @invisal range is 2-14

Comment: @Patchesoft, does $remove_values has to be in the array of above format? Can we change its structure?

Comment: @invisal You can change it if you want.

Comment: You can try to change `===` to `==`, it's a slight change but it may get faster because you don't check for equality type.

Comment: @Patchesoft - I posted an answer with an IDEONE.com benchmark so you can check it out. Basically using an associative array as a hash set for the remove_valus and then some bit fiddling using the result of ISSET to avoid having any branches (IF conditionals)

Comment: @Patchesoft I might be wrong but the you won't get better performance that you already have. I've tried all the answers on this page and none performed faster than yours

Comment: Here's the timing of all answers : http://ideone.com/snnajW , I guess it also depends on the php version and cpu. On my server `invisal CODE` is the fastest while in Ideone is the `Original CODE`

Comment: @Patchesoft are you alive?!

Comment: write the function in C and call it from your PHP script ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the function `in_array()` instead.

```
    if(in_array($card1, $remove_values)) {
        $card1 = 0;
    }
    if(in_array($card2, $remove_values)) {
        $card2 = 0;
    }
    if(in_array($card3, $remove_values)) {
        $card3 = 0;
    }
    if(in_array($card4, $remove_values)) {
        $card4 = 0;
    }
    if(in_array($card5, $remove_values)) {
        $card5 = 0;
    }
    if(in_array($card6, $remove_values)) {
        $card6 = 0;
    }
    if(in_array($card7, $remove_values)) {
        $card7 = 0;
    }
```

Comment: I guess this will have to check the array 7 times instead of only once.

Comment: Yes this takes 1.7 seconds longer than my current version. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how this might compare to the other answers or your own function in terms of speed but it might help.

```
    $cards=array(
        'card1' =>  1,
        'card2' =>  5,
        'card3' =>  6,
        'card4' =>  8,
        'card5' =>  10,
        'card6' =>  11,
        'card7' =>  12
    );  
    $remove_values = array(1,4,3,8,12); 

    function callback( &$item, $key, $removals ){
        if( in_array( $item, $removals ) ) $item=0; 
    }
    $result=array_walk( $cards, 'callback', $remove_values );
    if( $result ){
        echo '<pre>Cards:',PHP_EOL,print_r( $cards, true ),'</pre>';
    }

    /* Will output */

    Cards:
    Array
    (
        [card1] => 0
        [card2] => 5
        [card3] => 6
        [card4] => 0
        [card5] => 10
        [card6] => 11
        [card7] => 0
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could "break" the loop after setting a card equal to zero, so you would not evaluate the rest of the cases after that.

You could also try putting the card values into an array, and remove them as they are set to zero, so as you process cards you are searching a smaller array each time.  If you could sort the values and cards like a C++ map would, then that would be even faster for the search.

Comment: I've tried using a switch but It doesn't improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Using SplFixedArray will slightly improve the performance a bit.

```
$remove_values = new SplFixedArray(15);
$remove_values[1] = true;
$remove_values[4] = true;
$remove_values[3] = true;
$remove_values[8] = true;
$remove_values[12] = true;

if ($remove_values[$card1]) $card1 = 0;
if ($remove_values[$card2]) $card2 = 0;
if ($remove_values[$card3]) $card3 = 0;
if ($remove_values[$card4]) $card4 = 0;
if ($remove_values[$card5]) $card5 = 0;
if ($remove_values[$card6]) $card6 = 0;
if ($remove_values[$card7]) $card7 = 0;
```

You said that you will do million of loop. If the removed_values is unchanged, only the value of cards are changed, you can always do some preprocess the array of the remove values so that it will increase the speed even more.

Here is the speed performance comparison (one million loop)

```
                    | Normal Array | SplFixedArray
 Pre-Processing     |  4.2 seconds | 1.2 seconds
 Normal             |  5 seconds   | 4.2 seconds
```

Comment: where did you get `SplFixedArray ` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito, http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php. It is available on PHP 5.3.0+

Comment: Have you tried to run your code ? I've tried it and it doesn't do anything, not even error with `error_reporting` enabled. (I've PHP 5.4.45)

Comment: @PedreoLobito Did try it on my computer. Strange.

Comment: Can you post a sample on any online php IDE?

Comment: Ive' tried your code , it shows errors, take a look http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a74817de61bd4211e762b1cb1beb5820b2c60141

Comment: @PedroLobito, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/819ba2a5f2c5672394bfdb40ff91d6b32d909fa4

Comment: I could run the code but it's doesn't improve the timings, at least, with this example. also, `SplFixedArray` consumes more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an optimization that (in my kludgy IDEONE.com test) is 25% faster.
Use an associative array for the *remove_values* then do a key lookup *isset*.
If isset is true we want to remove the value so TRUE - 1 (0) & cardValue = 0, but if isset is false we want to keep the valu so FALSE - 1 (-1) & cardValue = cardValue. This is just some bit fiddling will preserve or zero the card value without having to do any conditional jumps.

```
$remove_values = array();
/* USE ASSOC. ARRAY */
for ($x = 0; $x <= 20; $x++) {
    $r = rand(2, 14);
    $remove_values[$r] = $r;
}
$card1 = rand(2, 14);
$card2 = rand(2, 14);
$card3 = rand(2, 14);
$card4 = rand(2, 14);
$card5 = rand(2, 14);
$card6 = rand(2, 14);
$card7 = rand(2, 14);
// Testing code
//
$card1 = (isset($remove_values[$card1]) - 1) & $card1;
$card2 = (isset($remove_values[$card2]) - 1) & $card2;
$card3 = (isset($remove_values[$card3]) - 1) & $card3;
$card4 = (isset($remove_values[$card4]) - 1) & $card4;
$card5 = (isset($remove_values[$card5]) - 1) & $card5;
$card6 = (isset($remove_values[$card6]) - 1) & $card6;
$card7 = (isset($remove_values[$card7]) - 1) & $card7;
```

Here's the IDEONE if you want to mess with it or try another version http://ideone.com/DDyQ4a

Comment: Ive tested the original code and it took my server `0.051975250244141ms` to run while yours  `0.11682510375977ms`

Comment: @PedroLobito - maybe you could add this "original code" into the ideone.com example I posted to find out what the disparity is. Knowing the answer to questions like (How many values should the remove_array have in it?) would probably be helpful.

Comment: You should test the code timings on a local server or at least on server that's not loaded (unlike ideone) because timings can vary.

Comment: It is better for you to show us how you measure the performance. It is like finding nail in the ocean without see-ing the complete picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PedroLobito - I'm using a benchmark loop of 10,000 iterations and running the loop twice to avoid that issue. Maybe the version of PHP on IDEONE is newer or the CPUs they are using are better able to optize the code.

Comment: @LouisRicci Take look at the timings of your code and the original code running on ideone http://ideone.com/OVKBEw

Comment: @PedroLobito - Your comparing apples and oranges. I was generating random values for the card variables and the remove_values array. The other test cases are using hard coded values, of course hard coded values will benchmark faster than randomly chosen values. In the real world your values will not be hard coded and the function will have to run mny times with many different values, so you should create a benchmark that mimics the real world.

Comment: The value of cards will be "harcoded" once you assign it to a variable. Why don't you post an example with "hardcoded" values so we can measure the timings ?

Comment: @PedroLobito - No, this is getting too silly for me, I'd recommnd you just use invisal 's version, it uses conditional statements instead of bit fiddling but should overall run better than your original code.

Comment: @LouisRicci It didn't make the question, I was just curious ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a curious challenge so I ran the 10,000 iterations as noted by the OP and used the timer helper class.

```
<?php
    class TimingHelper {
        private $start;
        public function __construct() {
            $this->start = microtime(true);
        }
        public function start() {
            $this->start = microtime(true);
        }
        public function segs() {
            return microtime(true) - $this->start;
        }
        public function time() {
            $segs = $this->segs();
            $days = floor($segs / 86400);
            $segs -= $days * 86400;
            $hours = floor($segs / 3600);
            $segs -= $hours * 3600;
            $mins = floor($segs / 60);
            $segs -= $mins * 60;
            $microsegs = ($segs - floor($segs)) * 1000;
            $segs = floor($segs);

            return 
                (empty($days) ? "" : $days . "d ") . 
                (empty($hours) ? "" : $hours . "h ") . 
                (empty($mins) ? "" : $mins . "m ") . 
                $segs . "s " .
                $microsegs . "ms";
        }
    }

    $cards=array(
        'card1' =>  1,
        'card2' =>  5,
        'card3' =>  6,
        'card4' =>  8,
        'card5' =>  10,
        'card6' =>  11,
        'card7' =>  12
    );  
    $remove_values = array(1,4,3,8,12); 

    function callback( &$item, $key, $removals ){
        if( in_array( $item, $removals ) ) $item=0; 
    }

    $th = new TimingHelper;
    $results=array();

    for( $i=0; $i < 10000; $i++ ){
        $th->start();
        $result=array_walk( $cards, 'callback', $remove_values );
        $results[]=$th->time();
    }

    echo min( $results );
    /* Outputs */
    /*
        -> 0s 0.0138282775879ms
    */
?>
```